# Azure Data Factory "Name File as column data" option in Sink transformation of data flow is creating blobs name for virtual folder

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I have create and ADF pipeline. Source and sink, both are storage account.
I want to create file based on date in column data, so I selected the option "File Name as Column Data".
In this option, we are giving filename, with virtual folder path.

But when process is completed, blob(hot inferred) also created for virtual folder, which I don't need. I just need blob for files(which is also present). If I delete those virtual folder blobs, I cant put the file in incremental way in those folder.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the column format first in source **projection** before set "File Name as Column Data".

**Here's my source file:**

[image]

**Source **projection** settings:** specify the column date type and format.

[image]

**Sink settings:**

[image]

Output:
[image]

Then we can get the output files without the virtual folder.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for the quick response. But i want my blobs in virtual folder. But i am also getting blobs of virtual folder which i dont want. Suppose, folder is “test”, a blob is also getting created as “test”, which i dont want.

Comment: @pankajsharma you could specify the folder name.

Comment: @pankajsharma do you have any other concerns? Please feel free to let me know. If my answer is helpful for you, really hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Where i have to specify the folder name. There are lot of folders at source side. It will take time to mention all of them. Anyway we changed the approach for now. Thanks!